# Why are some ruby integers not Marshal dumpable to_json

Tags: ruby, encoding, utf-8

Running this code slightly more than half of the integers can be parsed to json. I'm looking to understand the why here, let's assume I know nothing about encoding.

ruby 2.5.1

```
(1..1000).each do |i|
  begin
    Marshal.dump(i).to_json
    puts i
  rescue => e
    puts "#{i} #{e.message}"
  end
end


756"\xF4" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8
757"\xF5" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8
758"\xF6" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8
759"\xF7" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8
760"\xF8" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8
761"\xF9" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8
762"\xFA" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8
763"\xFB" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8
764"\xFC" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8
765"\xFD" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8
766"\xFE" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8
767"\xFF" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8
768
769
770
771
772
773
774
775
776
777
```

Comment: First you should do some research and learn about encodings. The answer is basically that `Marshal.dump` gives you ASCII-8BIT encoded strings but `String#to_json` wants UTF-8. Explaining encodings would probably be too broad.

Comment: Can you list some references?

Comment: Maybe start with the [character-encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/character-encoding/info) tag page.

Comment: @ChrisCPO just curious, why would you want to convert a ruby marshaled object to json?  Seems like you would either send the result directly (as a string) or serialize to json to begin with.

Comment: sorry went on vacation; currently using a new-ish gem "fie" to flush out a prototype web app that uses websockets for real-time updates, the marshal is stored in redis as json.